# Salah/fasting when menses don't stop for prolonged time

Tags: salat, sawm, menses

I have been suffering from PCOS for more than a decade. Sometimes the menses don't stop for weeks or even months (even almost 6 months at times with only spotting some days or normal flow the other days with no clean days in between)
I read somewhere a while ago that I can pray after 15 days even with the menses if they don't stop considering it as an illness.

The question is if I should be changing the products that I am using that could have the blood before every prayer or is it okay if I just do a wudhu and start praying considering it is not feasible changing all the time?
I am also hoping to fast on the 9th and 10th of this month but the menses have been going on for more than 20 days and also almost 2+ months if I consider the spotting. Is it okay if I fast and pray?